# Как выполнить сложение со строкой?

Tags: javascript

Как в данном случае можно произвести сложение? Сейчас результатом является строка.

```
console.log(2 + '+' + 2)
```

Comment: Убрав строку `'+'` из кода: `console.log(2 + 2)`. Или посчитав в уме: `console.log(4)`

Comment: честно говоря не понятный вопрос, может другие поймут...
а что должно быть в конечном итоге **4**? если да то просто **2+2** сделайте

Comment: Так как описали выше, можно конечно вывести и нужный результат 4, но необходимо тогда немного усложнить, но надо ли....??!!

Comment: В любом случае почитайте внимательно главу про преобразование типов. [Например тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion) или [тут.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Comment: Зачем это вообще нужно?

Answer (score 1):

> Как выполнить сложение со строкой?

Надо помнить, что `eval` это не самое хорошее решение, но если очень надо.

```js
// Числовые вычисления 
console.log(eval(2 + '+' + 2))
console.log(eval(2 + '**' + 3))

// Так же выражения типа
console.log(eval(2 + '<' + 5))
console.log(eval(2 + '>' + 5))
console.log(eval(2 + '===' + 2))

let x = 1;
let y = 4;

console.log(eval('x + y'))
```

[Док eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)